# How can I use Open GL ES to crop image?

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, uiimage, ios8

So I face some problems when I deal with image cropping. I am awared of two possible ways: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` combined with `drawAtPoint:blendMode:` methods and `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`. They both work but have some serious disadvantages:the first way takes a lot of time(in my case 7 secs approx.) and memory(I receive memory warning)(suppose I crop an image taken with iPhone camera); the second ends up with rotated image so that you need to put a bunch code to defeat this behavior which I don't want. What I want to know is how, for instance, apple's built in edit function of "Photos" app works, or Aviary or any other photo editor. Consider apple's editor(iOS 8), you can rotate image,change cropping rectangle,they also have blurring(!) outside the cropping rect and so on, but when you apply cropping it takes max 8 mb of memory and it happens immediately. How do they do this?

The only thought I have is that they use the potential of GPU(Aviary, for instance). So,if we combine all this questions in one, how can I use Open GL to make cropping be less painful operation? I've never worked with it, so any tuts,links and sources are welcome.Thank you in advance.

Comment: OpenGL and its derivatives are APIs for drawing stuff, that's ultimately to show up on a screen. The core purpose is the use in realtime graphics rendering. Your task is general purpose image manipulation, which is possible with OpenGL, but usually much easier done with special purpose image operation libraries.

Comment: @datenwolf Alright,could you name some of them,please?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned this should most likely not be done with openGL but even if...

The problem most people have is getting the rectangle in which the image should be displayed and the solution looks something like this:

```
- (CGRect)fillSizeForSource:(CGRect)source target:(CGRect)target
{
    if(source.size.width/source.size.height > target.size.width/target.size.height)
    {
        // keep target height and make the width larger
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(target.size.height * (source.size.width/source.size.height), target.size.height);
        return CGRectMake((target.size.width-newSize.width)*.5f, .0f, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    }
    else
    {
        // keep target width and make the height larger
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(target.size.width, target.size.width * (source.size.height/source.size.width));
        return CGRectMake(.0f, (target.size.height-newSize.height)*.5f, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    }
}

- (CGRect)fitSizeForSource:(CGRect)source target:(CGRect)target
{
    if(source.size.width/source.size.height < target.size.width/target.size.height)
    {
        // keep target height and make the width smaller
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(target.size.height * (source.size.width/source.size.height), target.size.height);
        return CGRectMake((target.size.width-newSize.width)*.5f, .0f, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    }
    else
    {
        // keep target width and make the height smaller
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(target.size.width, target.size.width * (source.size.height/source.size.width));
        return CGRectMake(.0f, (target.size.height-newSize.height)*.5f, newSize.width, newSize.height);
    }
}
```

I did not test this.

Or since you are on iOS simply create an image view with the desired size, add an image to it and then get the screenshot of the image.

Comment: So these methods will turn my source rect to the rect that is going to be used by CGImageCreateWithImageInRect?

Comment: This function creates a subimage with given rect which should work with fit method when one of the dimensions equals to the original image.. In other words: No, because it will not resize the image. You can use these methods to get a rect on where to draw the image onto the custom core graphic context (target size is should be the context size). Or you can use them to redraw the image with openGL. Or create a view with the target rect and add a subview image view to with the methods rect to get the same result...